# GPO: Preferences and Drive Maps not getting applied in second RD session

Tags: group-policy

I have a group policy object that maps several network drives. This is getting done via group policy preferences. When a user log's on to a remote desktop server the drives are getting connected - so far so good. However when the same user opens another remote desktop session to the same server the drives are not getting maped.

What am I doing wrong here? Any input on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This people are having the same issues but now solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3a46c92a-007f-4e1d-bc38-bea4d66b76de/server-2012-remote-desktop-remoteapp-no-gpp-mapped-drives-for-2nd-session?forum=winserverTS

Comment: When accessing the RDP sessions a second time, does _italic_ net use <driveletter> \\<UNC path>_italic_  able to manually map the drives?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes that maps the drive. It seams related to how the group policy engine handles client side extensions in this situation

Comment: Sounds like gpresult /v is going to be your friend here. Keep us updated if you find out!

Comment: according to gpresult /scope user /h out.html the drive mapping preferences are getting applied without any error or warning. so far so good... action is set to 'replace'... mmh

Comment: interesstingly when i run 'gpupdate /target:user' in session A, the desktop on session B get's updated. It seems to be some locking or registry access issue.

Comment: "action is set to 'replace' -" This would indicate you're doing this through loopback processing on a computer setting. I can see how this would definitely be troublesome on a terminal server environment. Can I ask why you are not applying these mapped drives directly to the user profiles through policy? **Disclaimer** at this point I no longer have any *experience* with this particular issue and am just trying to be helpful

Comment: Yes, that's right - loopback processing. The point is, that the user objects are wildly spread across the forest. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the "Reconnect" option within GPP has solved this "issue"...

Comment: Did you continue to use 'replace' with reconnect for consistent drive mappings or change to another option (i.e. create)?